# Is Investopedia wrong about a Collar's maximum loss and profit?

Tags: asset-pricing

[Are the last two paras. below correct?](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/collar.asp) Shouldn't they be reversed?

1. Isn't your maximum profit when $P \le 77$? Then you can exercise your 77P, but the call holder can't exercise his 97C. Your profit $= 77 - P -$ options premiums.
2. Isn't your maximum loss when $P \ge 97$? Then you can'texercise your 77P, but the call holder can exercise his 97C. Your loss $= P - 97 +$ options premiums.

[image]

> ### Collar Example
>
> Assume an investor is long 1,000 shares of stock ABC at a price of \$80 per share, and the stock is currently trading at \$87 per share. The investor wants to temporarily hedge the position due to the increase in the overall market's volatility.
>
> The investor purchases 10 put options (one option contract is 100 shares) with a strike price of \$77 and writes 10 call options with a strike price of \$97.
>
> Cost to implement collar (Buy Put @ \$77 & write Call @ \$87) is a net debit of \$1.50 / share.
>
> Break even point = \$80 + \$1.50 = \$81.50 / share.
>
> The maximum profit is \$15,500, or 10 contracts x 100 shares x ((\$97 - \$1.50) - \$80). This scenario occurs if the stock prices goes to \$97 or above.
>
> Conversely, the maximum loss is \$4,500, or 10 x 100 x (\$80 - (\$77 - \$1.50)). This scenario occurs if the stock price drops to \$77 or below.

Comment: This is probably better asked on the Quantitative Finance stack exchange https://quant.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

The Investopedia article is correct.

> Isn't your maximum profit when P≤77? Then you can exercise your 77P, but the call holder can't exercise his 97C. Your profit =77−P− options premiums.

You haven't accounted for the loss on the stock (Investopedia did).  It is:

- stock price + strike price - collar cost (-80 +77 -1.50)

> Isn't your maximum loss when P≥97? Then you can't exercise your 77P, but the call holder can exercise his 97C. Your loss =P−97+ options premiums.

You haven't accounted for the gain on the stock (Investopedia did).   It is:

- stock price + strike price - collar cost (-80 +97 -1.50)